Why does my GPU throttle when playing Borderlands 3 with friends?
When I play Borderlands 3 with my friends, my GPU throttles. How do I know this? By using HWiNFO64 and navigating to the GPU section, I can see that all the GPU performance limiters have a maximum value of "Yes" after the playing session. There are noticeable frame drops that make the game not fun to play (like 120 -> 20 -> 90 -> ???).
Attempted solutions so far:

I have updated my BIOS.
Updated Windows.
Uninstalled Armoury Crate (it was overriding my manual CPU fan profile).
Used MSI afterburner to make an aggressive GPU cooling curve (30C, 40% speed -> 60C, 100% fan speed).
Cleaned CPU cooler and removed dust, reapplied thermal paste. (temps look ok, no throttle)
Used compressed air to blow out GPU (temps look ok, but thermal throttle!?)
Followed this guide to reduce Borderlands 3 stuttering.

When looking at the logs, my GPU hotspot maxes out at 70.6C which is less than the set thermal throttling temp of 83C. However, the thermal throttle flag still gets flipped and I see bad lag spikes in game. My NVMe M.2 lists a max temp of 60C with no drive failures and 100% life remaining. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing my throttling issue? It's maddening for this to happen on a tower gaming PC.
See images for HWiNFO64 screenshots after a 2 hour playing session with 1 other friend.
System:

OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Home.
CPU: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700 @ 2.50GHz, 2496 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s).
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070: ASUS DUAL RTX 3070.
System: ASUS ROG Strix G15CE_G15CE
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. G15CE.312, 4/29/2024
RAM: 32.0 GB
Storage (for games, not OS): Samsung SSD 990 EVO 1TB (S7M3NS0X516204A).
Monitor: Sceptre M25 set to 120Hz -> Cap Borderlands 3 FPS at 120.

Screenshots:
GPU info:

CPU info:

System info:


I would look at your last screenshot which shows motherboard sensors TEMP2 and TEMP5 at 105C. Most likely those high temperatures are causing the system firmware to throttle the CPU down at 800MHz. Your CPU screenshot shows minimum speed of 800MHz which is a sign of thermal throttling. You can use a program called ThrottleStop (https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) and uncheck the BD PROCHOT signal to test. If everything now works then your firmware is slowing your CPU to protect other devices.

Note: Throttlestop is not and should never be considered a permanent solution. You should consult your motherboard manufacturer to find out what those sensors are and how to fix them. A BIOS update may help if they are simply being read wrong, or the hardware might need to be replaced.

Note2: BD PROCHOT means BiDirectional PROCessor HOT. It is a processor signal that is normally only emitted by the processor to tell the firmware the CPU is throttling due to high temperatures. In BD mode the signal becomes bidirectional and the firmware can tell the CPU to throttle as well as the CPU throttling itself. By unchecking the signal in throttlestop you limit the signal to CPU only control. Again this control should not be disabled in the long term. It looks like a device is overheating and should be investigated further.

@Mokubai Thanks for the input. Based on the googling I could do, it seems highly likely that for a Nuvoton NCT6798D these sensors (Temp2 and Temp5) are erroneous and not utilized.
